# how to count number of 1H candle between a single time till now?

Tags: pine-script, indicator

how to count number of 1H candle between a single time till now?

I want to calc max price in two time range (input time & now time) so I need an integer round number for highest() function like this:

```
highestHigh = highest(high, 2)[1]
```

this function calc 2 candle before, I want calc all candles between a specify date and time till now.

I tried many ways but can't resolve that (beginners ERORR :D )

something like this didn't work

```
firsttime = timestamp("GMT+4",2018,3,9,10,30) //input the first time
tillnow = hour(time-firsttime) //calc timestamp till now then convert to hours
rnd = round(tillnow) //not making a round number!

highestHigh = highest(high, rnd)[1]  //give me an error!
```

this error:
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 7: Cannot call `highest` with arguments (series, series[integer]); available overloads: highest(series, integer) => series; highest(integer) => series

how can do this in right way?

Answer (score 1):

[PineScript documentation on 'time'](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#var_time) is confusingly worded:

```
time

Current bar time in UNIX format. It is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 UTC, 1 January 1970.
```

time is a **series** of the UNIX time of the *specific* bar:
"What was the UNIX time at this, ith, bar?" time gives you that answer.

[timenow](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#var_timenow) is an **integer** of the current time and appears to be what you should use.

The function you're trying to build is similar to:

[Get 5-day high:
Lookback 5 days from the current bar, find the highest bar, plot a star character at that price level above the current bar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/HOWTOs.html#get-a-5-days-high)